# Flask set_cookie does not set cookie

Tags: python, flask

I've been having this big issue with my python code. I'm trying to set a cookie, and sometimes the cookie gets set, but most of the time it just doesn't. I've been trying to print out the value of the cookie, and quite often (most of the time) it's None. Can anyone please help me find out what I've done wrong? I appreciate all help. Thanks in advance

This is my run.py file

```py
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect, render_template, make_response
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(16)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    user = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    response = make_response('')
    response.set_cookie('id', 'test', domain='127.0.0.1')
    return redirect('home')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

And below here is my html code. (templates/home.html)

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Please login</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('login') }}">
        <input type="text" name="username">
    </br>
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you change your the part of your code to this

```
    response = make_response(redirect('/home')
    response.set_cookie('id', 'test')
    return response
```